# Which Python - Versions, locations and uses

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, version

I have 2 python locations.

**1st Location and Version:**

```
~$ which python
/Users/alejandrocampos/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Which corresponds to

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

**2nd Location and Version:**

```
~$ which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

Which corresponds to

```
Python 3.9.13 (main, May 24 2022, 21:13:51) 
[Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)] on darwin
```

I do not know exactly why and what implies...
How can I know which one is being used in Sublime text, Vs Code or Jupyter notebook?
How can I know which packets I have installed in each python version?

Thanks!

Comment: In code editors like VS Code and Sublime Text, you have the option of selecting which interpreter is used.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1:** *How can I know which one is being used in Sublime text, Vs Code or Jupyter notebook?*

Run the following code in any of those applications to get the Python version that it is using:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

**Question 2:** *How can I know which packets (sic) I have installed in each python version?*

If you meant "packages":

```
import sys
import pkg_resources

print(sys.version)
packages = pkg_resources.working_set
packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in packages])
for p in packages_list:
    print(p)
```

**Question 3:** Even though you did not ask the question, *"How do I set the Python version I want to use in Sublime text, VS Code or Jupyter Notebook?"*, here's some things you can try...

- In Sublime Text:

  - Select **Tools -> Build System -> New Build System**.
  - Enter the following text:

    ```
    {
        "cmd": [<Location of your Python Interpreter>, "-u", "$file"],
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "selector": "source.python",
    }
    ```
  - Save it as *Python.3.9.x.sublime-build*.
  - To run, select **Tools -> Build System -> Python.3.9.x**.
- In Jupyter Notebook: **Kernel -> Change kernel**
- In VS Code: In the Terminal, enter the Python executable path and the script path (e.g.,  `/Users/alejandrocampos/opt/anaconda3/bin/python "/home/alejandrocampos/workspace/stack/version.py"`)