# Weird version issue with python and VS code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, terminal

-Background-
I was having an issue with “import pygame” not working after I updated to python 3.11. So, I thought it was a version issue. VS code says the version is 3.11, but when I typed “python —-version” into my terminal, it said 3.9.12. Why is it showing an older version than I installed?

-What I Tried-
To try and find the problem, I deleted python 3.10 because I wasn’t using it, but I couldn’t find 3.9.12 anywhere in my applications or program files. Is there a proper way to locate it or uninstall that version somehow?

Comment: Check the order of Python folders of different versions in the environment variable (terminal always selects the first python program it finds), and you also need to install pygame for Python 3.11 (However, because Cython does not seem compatible with Python 3.11, the installation may not succeed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the Python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [which python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679135/which-python-versions-locations-and-uses).

You should also be able to select which python interpreter you want to use in vs code. For me clicking on the version number in the bottom bar of VS code opens up the 'select interpreter' option. You might also use (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Ultimately, it's a good practice to set up an [environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for each project to avoid version conflicts.

Comment: Ok. I tried that out and I found where it is. Apparently, that version is in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ , while the latest one is in ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311. The old interpreter says “Global” next to it. Is that the problem?

Comment: That solves the problem of which interpreter you are using and where they are installed. When you're using your desired interpreter you can use `pip list` to see which packages are installed for that interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such situations always use python virtualenv.

```
virtualenv -p python3.9 venv
```

This command will create virtualenv.

Press `shift + command + p` and search for `Python: Select Interpreter`.
this will show the available interpreted in your system. now select `venv` as the interpreter.